# undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm confused about this error. I'm getting it without any "firsts" anywhere . . .

The line that calls the error is the following:

```
= @wiki.creator.name
```

My wikis have many users, and my users have many wikis, through a table called Relationships (with attributes :wiki_id, :user_id, :creator_created). Creator is a method I defined in my wiki model:

```
has_many :relationships
has_many :users, through: :relationships

def creator
  self.relationships.find_by(:creator_created == true).user
end
```

This line was working yesterday, and I haven't done anything that should have changed it . . . but now I'm getting "Undefined method 'first' for nil:Nilclass."

I've checked, and @wiki and its relevant relationship are not nil, so I don't know what is . . .

Any thoughts?

Comment: Stacktrace please! BTW: `find_by(:creator_created == true)` is invalid. should be `find_by(creator_created: true)`

Comment: This happens because `self.relationships.find_by(:creator_created == true)` can't find any relationship object related to your object with the specified condition(s). It does return nil, then you try to call a method on a nil object (`.user` in your case)

Comment: Thanks BroiSatse! For some reason, this code has been working on other pages for weeks, but changing it does seem to have solved my problem. And MrYoshiji, I appreciate your explanation, but the issue was that user was *not* nil, and I was getting this error anyhow . . .

Comment: @EllenW - not that it has any impact on your issue, but just for your general understanding - you misunderstood @MrYoshiji's comment slightly. He was saying that your `find_by()` returned `nil` and then you're trying to call the `user` method on that `nil`, ie. you were effectively calling `nil.user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `find_by()` ends up calling `first` internally, which is where your error is probably coming from.

Not sure why you're getting the `nil` though because your `find_by` should resolve to `where(false)` which should still be a valid object, but try fixing that to what the commenters have suggested.